# Import 3D image

Tags: image3d

Is there a way of importing 3D images to Mathematica that will not be unicoloured? I would like to use a colourful 3D image in a discrete mapping so that one can visually see the transformation and relocation of the pixels.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may depend on the file format. Using Maya format, there are some examples of color 3D images here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Maya.html

Comment: You can import multiframe TIFF files using "Image3D" element: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TIFF.html